# User profile with devise, checklist app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to rails and I am currently in the process of developing a check list app.  I would greatly appreciate some guidance as I am currently suck in my development process and would just like some help getting me on my way.

**Goal:**

**Admins** will have the privileges to add collections, and add products to those specific collections - (all will be pre-populated and defined before the site goes live).

**Users** should arrive at the homepage, be presented with a splash page of what the page is and be able to sign in/ up.  Once signed in the user should be directed to their profile page.

a.) first time there, they should be presented with a list of collections they want to 'follow" / "watch" (that show up on their profile page to track the products they are missing from the entire collection)

b.) second time there, they should be presented with the collections they are watching, and the all products in that collection.

Once on their profile page, they should be able to "check" and "uncheck" products in the collection.  I want to show all the products in the collection regardless if they have them or not, and they can check the ones they have, and I will do some fancy front side stuff to make it visually appealing.  (fade from black / color - on true/false value - animate all selected ones to front of container..ect)

**What I have:**

I have a Collection(has_many) -> Products(belongs_to) association models set up.  I have both of the controllers CRUIDified, and the product page is CRUIDified through association with collection. (nested routes / @collection.products.build  etc.)

I have a generated Devise User model with email confirmation.  I gave that model a User(has_many) -> Collections(belongs_to) association.

**My next steps?**

I am trying to assign a user to a profile page that I can display the results of the their collections/products.  I am stuck as to how to achieve this.  Do I need to create a user controller and put a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` and limit the actions I don't want accessible by normal users? Or do I need to generate a new Model Profile, and put an association there?

If you would like to see my current code it can be found here:
https://github.com/gogogarrett/Blind-Boxd

Thanks in advance,

Garrett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a page for signed in users to see their collections and products, you don't necessarily need that to be in a User Controller.

I have put my user overview pages in a pages_controller. You then have a before filter of :authenticate_user!, and you just pass whatever you need into the view (@collections = current_user.collections).

It doesn't sound like you need a new model.